# Getting contacts from Google Api

Tags: google-api, google-contacts-api

I having problem while getting contacts of user form Google. So problem is Google Contacts contians user's mobile contacts (if sync to google) too, which i don't want to show to user. Here is my code:

```
        $.get("https://www.google.com/m8/feeds/contacts/default/full?alt=json&access_token=" + authResult.access_token + "&max-results=500&start-index=" + gPageInd + "&sortorder=ascending&sortBy=emails&v=3.0",function(response)
{
//code here 
});
```

i want only those records which have email and for that i tried to sort by email. i do not know that this is a right way to do this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[As stated in the documentation](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/contacts/v3/reference#Parameters), the only parameter supported by `sortedBy` is `lastmodified`. You will have to retrieve all the contacts and then filter in your code.